# Find the number of ways of placing m identical balls in n different boxes where each box can only have maximum of k balls and minimum of 0 balls

Tags: python, combinatorics

Given (m, n, k)
For (4, 3, 2) the answer is 6 
**Explanation**:
The first row tells that there are **2** balls in **box1**, **2** balls in **box2** and **0** balls in **box3**. This is one way of distributing 4 balls.
The other rows can be interpreted the same way. We can arrange 4 identical balls in 3 different boxes like below so there are 6 ways of distributing the balls.

| Box 1 | Box 2 | Box 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

Sample Inputs and Solutions:
(3, 3, 3)  =  **10**   (6, 4, 3)  =  **44**  (6, 4, 2)  =  **10** (3, 3, 2)  =  **7**

Is there any formula for this? or is there any dynamic programming approach for this?

I tried brute force approach where i iterated through all possible permutations and eliminated the repeating permutations. I am thinking that there should exist some dynamic programming approach or mathematical formula which should give me the result.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) can be helpful.

Comment: The solution by Prof. Brian Peterson is correct, it also handles the case where if `k` is so small that `k*n<m`, check [this](https://www.quora.com/In-how-many-ways-can-I-put-n-identical-balls-into-m-distinct-boxes-such-that-no-box-has-more-than-r-balls) out.

Comment: @GautamChettiar I have tried the summation formula mentioned in the link but it doesn't seem to work for the above inputs.

Comment: @bb1 I tried understanding the partitions from the link but i couldn't figure out a exact formula for my problem